# How to make it so no one can place blocks in spawn, using command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

This is for my server, and I am trying to make it so that you can run around with your items, but can't place any blocks to grief. How do I do this with command blocks?

Comment: My suggestion would be to not even bother trying.  Most servers come with options for spawn protection.  Use that instead of trying to hack something together.

Comment: As @MBraedley said, this is improbable. Even the default minecraft server.jar has spawn protection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change there gamemode to adventure when they are in the are of your spawn.

```
/gamemode @a[r=1000]
```

this could be the simplest way to do what you need.

Comment: OMG! I combed through google for an answer and found nothing! I tried everything! Thanks so much!!!!!!!

Comment: You are welcome.  Love to help.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to have a fill clock constantly cloning a regular lobby onto the one where the players are. This prevents people from making changes to your spawn, if you really want to use commands and commands only to do it.

Comment: Thank you. It will take a lot of work, put using setblock and clone, I think I will be able to do it.

Comment: No problem! I'm new to the site and this question/answer thing helped me understand what's going on, so thank you as well!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent them from destroying blocks, you can just apply the effect mining fatigue with a lever higher of 5 on every player near the spawn with a command block.

Comment: Thats exactly how I made that part.